# Node.js core module fallback in vite as webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vite

In webpack when I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: path.join is not a function" I could add the configuration

```
resolve: {
    fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }
}
```

to solve.

How do I do such thing in vite?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `resolve.alias` configuration option

```js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      path: 'path-browserify',
    },
  },
})
```

Documentation: https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias

Comment: What if it doesn't work?